# Plot3D won't run with a 2-variable function

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a 2 variable function that has some parameters as well. I defined it as:

```
f[x_,y_][pars_] := ...
```

where `pars` is the set of parameters. However, I can't plot the function. I tried to use:

```
Plot3D[f[x,y], ...]
```

and

```
Plot3D[f[x,y][pars], ...]
```

but neither work. The black bracket appears on the right and the program is running, but there is no output. How can I solve this?

Here's the link to the notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NdrBwRJ7BWaguXHxmt2bnJdkHhg5IIb4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why not  directily attach your code?

Comment: @cvgmt I tried at first, but the formatting looked messy, still need to work on that! But thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before pinning the blame on `Plot3D` look at the function you are feeding it.  If I run `B[-a, -a][pars]` in your notebook, it doesn't return in a timely manner.  Looking at the definition of `B` you have

```
B[x_, y_][pars_] := ...
```

but notice that `pars` doesn't show up on the right-hand side of that expression. So when you call `B` it doesn't get used, and the actual variables `Nm`, `Nn`, etc, remain undefined when calling `B`.

Instead do something like

```
B[x_, y_][pars_] := With[
    {Nm = Lookup[pars, Nm], Nn = Lookup[pars, Nn], <the rest of your variables>},
    <your big expression>
]
```

Since `pars` is a list of rules, this uses [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) to get the actual numeric values and then uses [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to make the substitution.

After this, I can check that it evaluates

```
In[44]:= B[-a, -a][pars]

Out[44]= 119996.
```

and it does so rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Subscript[B, 0] = 120000;  (* in G*)

Subscript[Φ, 0] = 
 2.0679*10^-7*10^16 // Rationalize;    (* in G A^2 *)

a = Sqrt[(2*Subscript[Φ, 0])/(Sqrt[3]*Subscript[B, 0])]; 
  K[m_, n_] = Sqrt[(2*Pi^2*Subscript[B, 0])/
           (Sqrt[3]*Subscript[Φ, 0])]*{(-Sqrt[3])*n, 
    2*m - n}; 
ξ0 = Sqrt[
    Subscript[Φ, 0]/(2*Pi*Hc2)] /. {Hc2 -> 350000}; 
pars = {ξ -> ξ0, λ -> 2700, Nn -> 2, Nm -> 2}; 

B[x_, y_][{ξ_?NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, Nn_Integer, Nm_Integer}] := 
   Subscript[B, 0] + Subscript[B, 0]*
       Sum[If[m == 0 && n == 0, 0, 
     If[K[n, m] . K[n, m]*ξ^2 < 0.05, 0, 
       Exp[(-ξ^2)*(K[m, n] . K[m, n]/2)]/
                 (1 + λ^2*K[m, n] . K[m, n])]*
      Cos[K[m, n] . {x, y}]], 
         {m, -Nm, Nm}, {n, -Nn, Nm}]

Plot3D[ 
 B[x, y][{ξ, λ, Nn, Nm} /. pars],
 {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[ 
 B[x, y][{ξ, λ, Nn, Nm} /. pars],
 {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a},
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Bmax = B[0, 0] [{ξ, λ, Nn, Nm} /. pars] // N

120011.

Bmin = N[B[a/2, a/(2*Sqrt[3])][{ξ, λ, Nn, Nm} /. pars]]

119995.
```